# how to use spreadsheet gem in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spreadsheet

Currently I am upgrading my Rails app from rails 3 to rails 4 and i am using spreadsheet(0.7.1)
after running server I got  **undefined method `send_file' for main::object**
this is my code:

```
def financial_export_excel
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    sheet = book.create_worksheet
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 0, 6, 0)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 1, 6, 1)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 2, 6, 2)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 3, 6, 3)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 4, 6, 4)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 5, 6, 5)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 6, 6, 6)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 7, 6, 7)
    sheet.merge_cells(5, 8, 6, 8)
    book.write "sample.xls"
    send_file "sample.xls"
    File.delete "sample.xls"
end
```

any help on this?

Comment: could you please add the whole stacktrace?

Comment: A little context would also be helpful.  Is this code part of a controller?  It presumably should be, since it depends on send_file while is a method on ActionController::DataStreaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your are storing the file in location and send it for download and finally delete it.

Since you deleted the file you con't get it for download. If you remove the line

```
File.delete "sample.xls"
```

it will work.

or you can use `send_data` method instead of `send_file` method.

eg:

> send_data book, :filename => "sample.xls", :type => 
>   "application/vnd.ms-excel"

reference 
[send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data)